# asp.net Gridview, 1 record span two rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm having trouble creating a `Gridview` that can span 2 rows for each record.
I've tried using a `templateField` with `headerTemplate` and `itemTemplates` as separate tables, but I can't get them to format correctly.

Does anybody know of an easier solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, don't use the GridView. A GridView is used to display tabular data. What you want doesn't fit that criteria. You could use a repeater however my preference is the new in 3.5 [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  >
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%# Eval("Something") %>
      </td>        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <%# Eval("SomethingElse") %>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>

  <EmptyDataTemplate>
    <div>
          No data was returned.</td>
      </div>        
  </EmptyDataTemplate> 
  <LayoutTemplate>          
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
  </LayoutTemplate> 
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: In addition to this, in asp.net 4.0 you wont need the <LayoutTemplate> part for the ListView, making it even more straightforward.

Comment: The list view works great.  Thank you very much.  The only thing left for me to do is sort by the column headings.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) instead of a GridView? The Repeater is probably the easiest way to have 2 rows per record, you get more control over the tabular markup that gets generated e.g.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" >
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Field 2</th>
        </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field1") %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "field2") %></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```