# GridView Column with long text

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a number of columns and it is all populating how I want it however one of the columns can have quite a bit of text in it.  To try and present it nicely I'd prefer to be able to show that column in the row under it, so spanned across all columns:

As a simplified example currently I have:

```
Name  DOB        Sex  Comments   Title
Ian   15/04/2015 M    This is    MR
                      the text
                      that keeps
                      wrapping
```

I'd prefer it to be something like

```
Name  DOB        Sex  Comments   Title
Ian   15/04/2015 M    This is    MR
Comments: This is the text that keeps wrapping
```

Obviously this is a very simplified example but hopefully it explains what I'm trying to do.  The current GridView code I have is below, I'm wanting to move `intScore` to the next row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwClinical" runat="server" DataKeyNames="intClinicalAssessID"     OnRowDataBound="gvwGrids_RowBound" OnRowDeleting="gvwGrids_Delete"    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvwClinical_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSorting="gvwSort"   OnPageIndexChanging="gvwPage">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="intClinicalAssessID"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="View" CommandName="Select" ButtonType="image"></asp:ButtonField>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ButtonType="image"></asp:ButtonField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dteAssessmentDate" HeaderText="Assess. Date" SortExpression="dteAssessmentDate"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intScores" HeaderText="Scores" SortExpression="intScores" HtmlEncode="false"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intHeight" HeaderText="Height" SortExpression="intHeight"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intWeight" HeaderText="Weight" SortExpression="intWeight"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strWellBeing" HeaderText="Gen Well Being" SortExpression="strWellBeing"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strAbdominalPain" HeaderText="Abdo Pain" SortExpression="strAbdominalPain"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strAbdominalMass" HeaderText="Abdo Mass" SortExpression="strAbdominalMass"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strBowelFreqDay" HeaderText="Bowel Freq (day)" SortExpression="strBowelFreqDay"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strBowelFreqNight" HeaderText="Bowel Freq (night)" SortExpression="strBowelFreqNight"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strStoolUrgency" HeaderText="Defecation Urgency" SortExpression="strStoolUrgency"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intLiquidStoolCount" HeaderText="Lq Stools 24 Hrs" SortExpression="intLiquidStoolCount"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strRectalBleeding" HeaderText="Rectal Bleeding" SortExpression="strRectalBleeding"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strEndoscopyFindings" HeaderText="Endo Findings" SortExpression="strEndoscopyFindings"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strGlobalAssess" HeaderText="Gbl Assessment" SortExpression="strGlobalAssess"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intActiveFistula" HeaderText="Active Fistula" SortExpression="intActiveFistula"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intTemperature" HeaderText="Temp." SortExpression="intTemperature"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intPulse" HeaderText="Pulse" SortExpression="intPulse"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intHB" HeaderText="Hb" SortExpression="intHB"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intHCT" HeaderText="Hct" SortExpression="intHCT"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="intCRP" HeaderText="CRP" SortExpression="intCRP"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="strComplications" HeaderText="Complications" SortExpression="strComplications"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Use `Repeater` for this approach.

Comment: As Bharadwaj said use repeater for this kind of purpose. It very hard to achieve this kind of functionalisties with Gridview and you have to write unnecessary code for that. With repeater you can easily create those things.

Comment: yes, i too agree with Bharadwaj.

Comment: Here is a link which can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637971/asp-net-gridview-1-record-span-two-rows

Comment: I like to use tooltips to display long text rather than have it crowd my table. Then again, I use the [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.110).aspx) combined with [jQuery DataTable](http://datatables.net/). Repeaters give you must finer grained control over what to do with your content, and you can easily hook them up to client side table libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TemplateField for this. This will enable you to put the longer text underneath the rest of the fields since you can design the layout per column, or row if you use only one TemplateField. you can Bind and Eval as many DataFields and html in one TemplateField as you desire if your DataSource provides them:

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header1" SortExpression="fieldname1">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("fieldname1") %>'></asp:Label>
       <hr>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("fieldname2") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Please note tough that this will come with side effects. You can only add a Column Header for each TemplateField you add, so ordering your data for each DataField can become tricky or pretty much impossible with the default setup from a GridView when using these fields. Since TemplateFields behave like normal BoundFields it is possible to combine BoundFields and TemplateFields in a row, but you cannot let a TemplateField show up underneath the other Columns.

As far as i know it's impossible to use BoundFields in a TemplateField, and if that's really what you are searching for maybe looking for a Pivot grid would be a better idea. But if the highly configurability and footprint of a Pivot grid suits your solution is another question.

Hope this helps in finding an awnser to your challenge. Good Luck!